# Combining VLOOKUP, IF OR, and STDEV

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, standard-deviation

In Excel I have two columns. One has a player's name and the other has points scored. Like this:

```
Player  Points
Foo     10
Bar     11
Foo     23
Test    9
Joe     1
Foo     2
```

What I'm trying to do is get the standard deviation of the points for a combined list of players.

For example, if I had this list:

```
Foo
Bar
```

I would want the standard devation of 10, 11, 23, and 2, since those are the values that match those two players.

I have tried this formula:

```
=STDEV(IF(OR(A:A="Foo",A:A="Bar"),B:B,""))
```

but I get a different answer than if I were to use the STDEV formula on the individual numbers that it should be using.

Anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=STDEV(IF((A:A="Foo")+(A:A="Bar")>0;B:B))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that isn't working.

Comment: Ha, I posted one minute before you corrected this, but your answer is cleaner.  You should get the credit.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula doesn't work, because `OR` returns true if *any* of its arguments are true.  Since there's at least one Foo in your list, `OR` always returns true, so `IF` returns all values in the `B` column.

You can see this by entering: `=OR(A:A="Foo")`.  It will show `TRUE`.

An alternative is to do a substring search, such as `FIND("|"&A:A&"|","|Foo|Bar|")`.

I'm using pipes (|) as delimiters.

This will return #VALUE! when not found, but you can use `ISNUMBER` to return false in those cases.

Your formula then becomes `=STDEV(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("|"&A:A&"|","|Foo|Bar|")),B:B))`.

Enter as an array formula:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Array formulas can be really slow when working on entire columns.  So you may want to restrict the data to the actual range – A2:A7 and B2:B7 in this example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Rick is right, but a simpler way to "correct" `OR`s behaviour is to use the simple `+` in its place (needs to be array formula, so entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)-->

```
=STDEV(IF((A:A="Foo")+(A:A="Bar"),B:B,""))
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?  :)