# Using STDEV.S with VLOOKUP, or alternate solutions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, stdev

In Excel, I have two columns. One has a category name and the other has a number against the category like this:

[Category List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT4cm.png)

What I'm trying to do is get the standard deviation of the points for each individual category, in a 3rd column.

For example, if I had the above data set, the Category STDEV.S column would show:
[Category List 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCp0q.png)

I would want the standard deviation of 10, 7 and 7 to show against each category that shows as "Fruit", and the standard deviation of 11, 5 and 7 to show against each category that shows as "Starch".

I tried referring to this thread as a reference, but could not get the formula to work: [Combining VLOOKUP, IF OR, and STDEV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794039/combining-vlookup-if-or-and-stdev)

Comment: what was the formula you tried? it could be as simple as forgetting the last step of using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

use this array formula:

```
=STDEV.S(IF($G$2:$G$13=G2,$H$2:$H$13))
```

Confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]